# python dictionary to pandas dataframe returns empty dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dictionary

I have a dictionary created run-time in my program which needs to be converted to a pandas dataframe.

`dictio={'a':'abc','b':'zyx','c':'prq'}
df=pd.Dataframe(dictio)`

The above code returns me an empty dataframe with columns created. Can anyone point to what am i missing out?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
#use from_dict and set orient to index and then transpose in the end.
pd.DataFrame.from_dict(dictio,orient='index').T
Out[263]: 
     a    c    b
0  abc  prq  zyx
```

Comment: This works but I want the result to be in a transposed format, as in the dictionary keys should be column names.

Comment: Keys(a,b,c) are the column names here. What' your expected results?

Comment: I believe the example I have provided isn't enough, I have an empty dictionary set up with large number of columns whose values get set during the program. Converting into data-frame gives me using what was suggested dictionary keys as first column and 0 as another.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand you problem. Please provide an example with more data and your desired output.